# HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127fn returns Supply Memory Error attempting to print long documents

Tags: windows-7, printer, hp-laserjet, toner

When I try to print a long document (e.g. 10 pages) to an HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127fn printer, it prints only the first few (3-5) pages, then stops with a Supply Memory Error message on the front panel. I'm printing from a system running Windows 7 Professional x64.

I tried searching Google and HP Support ([1](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/10-0000-SUPPLY-MEMORY-ERROR/td-p/541579), [2](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/What-is-a-supply-memory-error-10-1000-How-can-I-fix-it-My/td-p/1099987)) and could not find an answer. Resetting the printer did not help.

Comment: "supply memory warning" should be followed by an error number. What is that number?

Comment: something 10.000

Comment: If you have tried the suggestions given in the links you gave, try a factory reset. See http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01998773

Comment: What solved it? If one of your links did, please put it in as an answer; if factory reset did it, I'll put in an answer to that effect.

Comment: one of my research. it was fault of cartridge. chip was heating.

Comment: i instructed by that link https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/What-is-a-supply-memory-error-10-1000-How-can-I-fix-it-My/td-p/1099987

Comment: If you put that link (and a description of what it says to prevent link rot) you can accept your answer and score some points for future use.

Comment: what should i do next?

Comment: Post your answer in the "Your answer" box, and then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this HP Support forum thread](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/What-is-a-supply-memory-error-10-1000-How-can-I-fix-it-My/td-p/1099987), it was a faulty print cartridge:

> Remove the affected cartridge. Look at where the chip on the cartridge hits the reader at the rear of the machine. There are two triangular 'wires' which hit the chip.
>
> In all cases of this error which I have dealt with (I'm a reseller) one or both have been pushed into the mount and are failing to spring out when the cartridge is removed.  This prevents the chip from being read.
>
> The solution? Grab them and gently pull them proud again so that the inserted cartridge makes firm contact with them.